# Issue while Making shopping cart

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart

[image]
[image]

So I was programing shopping cart project and I have a issue.

I wanted to display the details of the data stored in local storage in cart.html. When running the code the program cannot find .name or anything in data.js and returns with undefined or async image rather than actual image or name

Without the search function, in console I can see the things that are in the cart with all its details example: id, name, desc, so on...

I wanted the program to function in such a way that 'if' the cart has data display the contents 'else' say cart is empty and button which says return to home.

The if and else function are both functioning fine the only issue is with displaying the contents

Would really appreciate if you can provide the correction and proper guidance, thanks in advance!

**part of cart.html**

```
<div id="label" class="text-center"></div>


      <div id="shopping-cart" class="shopping-cart"></div>


    </body>
    <script src="src/data.js"></script>
    <script src="src/cart.js"></script>
</html>
```

**cart.js**

```
let label = document.getElementById('label');
let shoppingCart = document.getElementById('shopping-cart');


let basket = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data")) || [];


let calculation = () => {
    let cartIcon = document.getElementById("cartAmount");
    cartIcon.innerHTML = basket.map((x) => x.item).reduce((x, y) => x + y, 0);
};

calculation();


let generateCartItems = () => {

    if (basket.length !== 0) {
        return (shoppingCart.innerHTML = basket
            .map((x) => {
                console.log(x);
                let {
                    id,
                    item
                } = x;
                let search = shopItemsData.find((y) => y.id === id) || [];
                return `
            <div class="cart-item">
                <h2>${search.name} has been added</h2>
            </div>
            `;
            })
            .join(''));
    } else {
        shoppingCart.innerHTML = ;
        label.innerHTML = `
        <h2>Cart is EMPTY!</h2><br>
        <a href="index.html">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Back to Home!</button>
        </a>
        `;
    }
};

generateCartItems();
```

**data.js**

```
let shopItemsData = [
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Silver Wash",
        price: 499,
        desc: "This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.",
        img: "images/silver.jpg"
    },
    {
        id: "2",
        name: "Gold Wash",
        price: 999,
        desc: "This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.",
        img: "images/gold1.jpg"
    }];
```

Now in the index.html I have programed the cards with the value in index.html itself and made separate data.js for .js files to be used in other .js files example of index.html shown below:

```
<div class="shop" id="shop">

        <div id=product-id-1 class="card mb-3">
          <div class="row g-0">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <img src="images/silver.jpg" class="img-fluid rounded-start" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Silver Wash</h5>
                <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.
                  This content is a little bit longer.
                </p>
                <br>
                <button type="button" onclick="add(1)" class="btn btn-primary">@499 | Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you checked your developer console? Are you using any additional libraries? `return <div class="cart-item"> <h2>${itemName} has been added</h2></div>` isn't valid in vanilla Javascript.

Comment: Typo?  `return` on a line by itself will simply *return*.  Maybe you meant to wrap the result in parentheses?  (This is also a good time to get in the habit of consistently using semi-colons.)

Comment: Sorry there was typo, Stackoverflow wasn't allowing me to post code due to formatting issue, so fixed it. still doesn't work

Comment: Have you checked your developer console? "Still doesn't work" isn't particularly helpful. Where is it failing?

Comment: @DhruvGiri: Can you update the question to include a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example?

Comment: No error on search.name but the output is undefined (output should be actual name from data.js) and if used search.image the error on console is image async error

Comment: @David sorry I wouldn't be able to because there are multiple files but I have attached screen shot from server of console and actual output. It is detecting that there are 2 items thus showing 2 undefined items but not the actual name of those items

Comment: @mykaf I have attached the screenshot please check

Comment: @DhruvGiri: Then what debugging *have* you done?  When you debug, why *specifically* do you expect `search` to have a `name` property?  What *does* `search` have?  If you can't provide an example which demonstrates the problem then you need to do the debugging to narrow down the problem.

Comment: @David I have attached an image from debugger can you please explain?

Comment: @DhruvGiri: It appears that `search` is an empty array.  Arrays indeed have no property called `name` so that property would be `undefined`.  It's also worth noting that the code in that image is different from the code you're asking about in the question.  In the question `search` defaults to an empty object, not an array.  (Though an empty object still also have no `name` property.)

Comment: @David right so it wasn't supposed to be an object but array. I am trying to pull out data from data.js which has shopItemsData in that there is name. So What should I do to get the name from that and show it? Also thing to note in console shows the object not and array of objects with the current code

Comment: @DhruvGiri: *"it wasn't supposed to be an object but array"* - An array will never have a property called `name` (unless you add one, but why would you).  And `.find()` returns an object, not an array.  You seem to be inconsistent on what you expect the `search` variable to actually contain.  You'll definitely need to understand your data types first, before you can successfully write code which uses them.

Comment: @David the issue had been resolved. You were right I was mismatching the data types. All I had to do is y.id === id.toString(). Well thanks for helping me out and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the cart.js file. It was a data type mismatch, such as comparing a string id to a numeric id, or vice versa. To address this issue, let's ensure that we're comparing the same data types.

```
let generateCartItems = () => {

if (basket.length !== 0) {
    return (shoppingCart.innerHTML = basket
        .map((x) => {
            console.log("ID:", x.id); // Log the id
            console.log("shopItemsData:", shopItemsData); // Log the shopItemsData array
            console.log(x);
            let {id} = x;
            let search = shopItemsData.find((y) => y.id === id.toString()); //Here y.id === id.toString not just id
            console.log("Search result:", search); // Log the search result
            return `
        <div class="cart-item">
            <h2>${search ? search.name : "Unknown item"} has been added</h2>
        </div>
        `;
        })
        .join(''));
}else{};
```